# Can't submit a form dynamically via JavaScript in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, dom, plugins

I'm working on the backend settings of a Wordpress plugin and thought I'd build a simple table enable editing of the data in the Custom Options menu of the plugin.

In case you are looking at the screenshot and wondering, it is a data on the anniversaries of loved ones who have passed away in previous years, known in Church as "the Year's Mind". Nothing sinister, I assure you!

The PHP is

```
$html .= "<form name='updateRow_". $post->ID ." method='post' action='includes/yearsmind-update.php'>";
              $html .= "<input type='hidden' name='ID' value='" . $post->ID . "'>";
              $html .= "<input type='hidden' name='firstName' value='" . $post->firstName . "'>";
              $html .= "<input type='hidden' name='middleName' value='" . $post->middleName . "'>";
              $html .= "<input type='hidden' name='lastName' value='" . $post->lastName . "'>";
              $html .= "<input type='hidden' name='fullDate' value='" . $post->fullDate . "'></form>";
```

The button is:

```
<button type='button' onclick='document.updateRow_".$post->ID.".submit()')>Update</button>
```

The $html string is written out nicely to the backend, and when I click on the update button, I can pick up the javascript function and display the passed **$post->ID**

[Backend output as desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEvqk.png)

However, I cannot seem to programmatically submit the specified form. The **submit** method  throws an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'submit')`

I have tried just passing a reference to the form via Form ID which gets through to a JavaScript function and displays passed reference, fine, but as the button can only be clicked after the form has fully loaded, it seems that none of the `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {`   events make any difference.

I have tried to simplify it by programming in the submit code into the form, and still it is throwing up an error!

Once the form is submitted to a PHP file, I plan to construct the UPDATE sql and execute it, but I'd just like to get the data POSTed first!

I bet the solution is obvious, but I can't work out the solution without your generous help...  Thank you.

Comment: Is the button inside the form it's supposed to submit?  If so, you don't need any javascript, as the default action of a button in a form is to submit that form.

Comment: `document.querySelector('#updateRow_".$post->ID."').submit()`

Comment: I just want to throw another option out there, separate your HTML and JavaScript completely. Tag your HTML "somehow", then write some JS to look for those tags and do "something". In [this sample](https://codepen.io/cjhaas/pen/jOeMjox), I've given the forms and buttons tags in a similar fashion to yours, except using data attributes which can be whatever you want. Then in pure JS I'm looking for those tags and binding the events. `onclick` isn't wrong, but you are really limited in space and are forced to deal with escaping and such.